# Rxjs : [ts] Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<string | {}>>'. any

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular5, rxjs5

I'm trying to implement ngbTypeAhead , but having an issue with RxJS , using 5.5.5 version . I've took this example from rxjs 6 version .

```
"rxjs": "^5.5.2" and
 angular "^5.0.1",
"typescript": "~2.6.1",
```

when I tried to implement typeahead on focus , getting an error like ,

```
 *[ts] Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<string | {}>>'.
any*


search2 = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged());
    const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()));
    const inputFocus$ = this.focus$;

    let mer = merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$);
    debugger;
    return mer.pipe(
      map(term => (term === '' ? this.roadList
        : this.roadList.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
    );
  }
```

could anyone please help me figure it the issue how to rewrite the above search2 method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're most likely importing `merge` as an operator while you want `merge` that it so called *"Observable creation method"* and comes directly form `'rxjs'`.

So check if you're really using this import in RxJS 6:

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
```

...instead of this import that imports `merge` operator that you don't want:

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs/operators'; // This imports just the operator
```

For RxJS 5 use the following:

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge';
```

Comment: when i import like this , import { merge } from 'rxjs';  getting an error as  /apps/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'merge'.

Comment: solved like this import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge'; thanks !

Comment: I forgot to mention that what I posted was for RxJS 6. For RxJS 5 it's correct to import as you did

Comment: @AhammadaliPK Updated